Repeated horizontal lines on AOC monitor
I noticed the problem 2 days ago and today wanted to research it. I've been seeing tiny 1 pixel horizontal lines on my screen that are barely visible on 240Hz, but when I'm starting my PC the problem is obvious:

I'm starting to get worried that it might be my GPU causing this, since the problem is dependent on the refresh rate, but I'm no technician and really need to know what I need to replace or fix to have the problem go away.
I will attach more reference pics and give more data below.

240Hz, 120Hz, 60Hz.

CPU: Ryzen 5 5600X
GPU: Gigabyte RTX 3060 12GB (Bought new about 2 years ago)
Monitor: AOC 24G2ZE [240Hz, 24"] (Bought new about 1.5 years ago)

I have a decent PSU so I know the GPU is getting enough power, I'm using DP to connect my monitor and I haven't done any changes to how I use my monitor before I started seeing it break.

This is most likely the display. At work, I got a new screen, and out of the blue it would start a certain color to change to a different color, and sometimes it would produce lines similarly to your screen, but not the entire screen, but certain groups of vertical lines. If I turned off the monitor and back on, the problem would instantly go away, and could stay away for weeks. The monitor was still in warrantee so we replaced it. We ruled out a faulty cable by replacing the cable but getting the problem back instantly.
